# permissions for Administrator accidentally removed - sonarqube.com

Tags: permissions, sonarqube

I am using [sonarqube.com](https://sonarqube.com) with [Travis](https://travis-ci.org) for on of my project: [Cognifide/aet](https://github.com/Cognifide/aet). While granting permissions for my colleague I have probably:

1. Selected all available permissions
2. Clicked *Apply Template* button

[image: How i tried to add administrative permissions]

Now me and my colleague have an issue with permissions: neither of us can see the *Administration* tab for the [Cognifide/aet](https://sonarqube.com/dashboard/index/com.cognifide.aet:aet-root) project. The Travis builds are failing for [my colleague's token](https://travis-ci.org/Cognifide/aet/builds/178108134) as well as for [mine](https://travis-ci.org/Cognifide/aet/builds/177902232).

There is already similar question: [permissions for Administrator accidentally removed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34271997/1823545),
but I don't have access to database in this case.

What can I do in order to reset the permissions? If it would be easier to delete this project and add it again for [sonarqube.com](https://sonarqube.com/dashboard/index/com.cognifide.aet:aet-root) then it is also acceptable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By applying templates (predefined values), you've removed your own account.
Please contact us with this form : https://about.sonarqube.com/contact/